# ffmpeg works from terminal but not by php script

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have to get the thumbnail image of video i am using the ffmpeg. On my server i run the ffmpeg command from ssh then it is working but from the php exec function it is not working it gives the error /usr/bin/ffmpeg : no such file or dirctory but the ffmpeg is installed on this location usr/bin/ffmpeg.
my source code is:

```
$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';

$videoname = 'myvideo.mp4';

$video = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/videos/'.$videoname;

$image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/thumbs/thumb.jpg';

$second = 1;

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";

exec($cmd);
```

Please provide any solution.

Comment: Instead of just running `exec()` and assuming that you've not made a mistake, why not print the command that's being run and verify that it's correct?

Comment: My root path is correct as i print the command:

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i path_to_video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg Path_to_thumb 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

Update you code with this one you will be good to go.

> `$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';
>
> $videoname = 'myvideo.mp4';
>
> $video = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/videos/'.$videoname;
>
> $image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/thumbs/thumb.jpg';
>
> $second = 1;
>
> $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i '".$video."' -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t
> 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg '".$image."' 2>&1"; echo $cmd;
> exec($cmd);`

Sometimes `exec()` function miss behaves due to missing quotes around variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use **shell_exec** instead of **exec**

```
$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';

$videoname = 'myvideo.mp4';

$video = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/videos/'.$videoname;

$image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/thumbs/thumb.jpg';

$second = 1;

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";

shell_exec($cmd);
```